# How to create a single migration for a specific model using C# ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to develop a small application using ASP.NET MVC 5.

I am using Entity Framework with a code first approach.

To get started, I created my first model and then followed the steps below to create the table in the database

1. I opened the Package Manager Console
2. I executed `Enable-Migrations`
3. I executed `Add-Migration InitilizeModel1Table`
4. Finally, to create the table I executed `Database-Update`

In step 3 created a migration called `datetime_InitilizeModel1Table` which created the code that will create the table automatically.

In step 4, it applied the create table command and created the table in the database as expected.

Now, I created 3 more models and what I like to do is create a separate migration for each to keep my code separated.

So I thought I would start again at step 2 and so the following

1. `Add-Migration InitilizeModel2Table`
2. `Add-Migration InitilizeModel3Table`
3. `Add-Migration InitilizeModel4Table`
4. `Database-Update`

But the command `Add-Migration InitilizeModel2Table` is creating an empty migration without the code that is needed to create the tables.

Here is an example of one

```
namespace App.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class InitilizeModel2Table : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {

        }

        public override void Down()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How can I create a new migration for each model without having to manually write the migration script to create the tables?

Comment: If you want separate migrations for each model, you'll have to add them one at a time and create a migration between each creation. EF obviously is not picking up your new models, did you create them in the same manner as your original model?

Comment: I believe I did. all I did was right click on the Models folder, Add New, Class. they typed the class name.

Comment: Did you add the new models to your context?

Comment: @SvenGrosen I did not :) which is why it was creating an empty migrations :)  How does the command Add-Migration know which model to choose when creatingthe migration? does it look for anything that does not have a migration and creates it? so If I put one model at a time in the context class I would get one migration class per model?

Comment: `Add-Migration` will look for all changes EF does not know about. Regarding your question on getting one migration per model, yes, that is my understanding.

Comment: Thank you very much. if you post an answer I will accept it. How does EF link the migration to the model, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was that you weren't adding your models to the context, hence EF did not detect the changes.

EF links the state of the model to the migration via the `__MigrationHistory` table/the migration files themselves. It compares the latest value in `__MigrationHistory` to the current state of your context, if they are different then a new, non-empty migration will be created when you run `Add-Migration X`.

Here are a [couple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) of [resources](http://wakeupandcode.com/entity-framework-code-first-migrations/) describing code-first migrations.

I am by no means an EF expert, so I may be slightly off in the details here.